# Sticky Navigation Bar Functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to create a sticky navigation bar using jQuery waypoints. I don't know a ton about Javascript so I'm trying to piece together from the examples.

Here is the navigation I'm using:

```
    <section id="nav">

    <div class="container">
        <div id="mainnav">
            <nav id="myNavigation" class="horizontal_nav pageScrollerNav topNav sixteen columns alpha">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-picture"></i> Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-list-ul"></i> Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-comments"></i> Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-rss"></i> Follow Me</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div> <!--end mainnav-->
    </div> <!--end nav-container-->

</section> <!--end nav-->
```

And here's the jQuery I have setup:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.top').addClass('hidden');
    $.waypoints.settings.scrollThrottle = 30;
    $('#mainnav').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
        $('.top').toggleClass('hidden', direction === "up");
    }, {
        offset: '-100%'
    }).find('#myNavigation').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('sticky', direction === "down");
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

I appreciate all of your help!

Comment: i'd post the code if you don't want your site to be swamped. Also it's just good etiquette

Comment: Thanks, posted the code instead. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a class like:

```
.nav-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

You can write some jQuery like so (modified from code written for Twitter's Bootstrap documentation page). It will monitor your navigation element. When it reaches the top of the screen, it will get the `nav-fixed` class which will fix the element to the top left corner of the page.

```
var $window = $(window),
    $nav = $('#navigation'),
    nav_top = $nav.offset().top,
    isNavFixed = false;

$window.on('scroll',checkNav); // call function when page scrolls

checkNav(); // initial call to function on document ready

function checkNav() {
    var scroll_top = $window.scrollTop();

    if(scroll_top >= nav_top && !isNavFixed) {
        isNavFixed = true;
        $nav.addClass('nav-fixed');
    } else if(scroll_top <= nav_top && isNavFixed) {
        isNavFixed = false;
        $nav.removeClass('nav-fixed');
    }
}
```

You can modify this code as needed to use your waypoints plugin.